# Using Groovy create Project properties in SoapUI

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have 50+ tests in my current SoapUI workspace. I need to add a new project level parameter on all of these tests. Is there a way I can do this using the groovy console within SoapUI?

For example :

```
  testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue( "SuperMan",("SuperMan"));
```

I can run this to create a property within the current working project. 
Is there a way I can create this under all projects on my current workspace?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, We can do this but it's little tricky.

**Way to do this:**

1. Create a empty generic project in soapui, Add empty testsuite, add Empty testcase
2. In test case Add a groovy script step
3. Now paste this groovy code

   ```
   for(project in com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI.workspace.projectList) {    
    if(project.open && project.name != testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.name){
          project.setPropertyValue( "TestProperty","TestValue");    
    }    
   }
   ```

Run the groovy step, you will get property added at Project level.

Please mark this as correct response if this solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Using your `testRunner` access you simply need one level more [`workspace`](https://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/impl/WorkspaceImpl.html). From here you can access `projects` map and iterate over each project adding the property:

```
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.workspace.projects.each{ key, proj ->
    proj.setPropertyValue('superman','superman')
}
```

This code doesn't add the property on closed projects in workspace but not fails accessing it.

Alternatively as @Rao suggest on his comment it's possible to use default `it` object iterator and access the `value` instead of defining `key, proj ->` on `each`:

```
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.workspace.projects.each{ 
    it.value.setPropertyValue('superman','superman')
}
```

I prefer the first approach for clarity.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Well, it works. `key` may not really required though there is no harm.

Comment: @Rao I use `key,proj ->` for clarity, but yes of course the OP can use default `it` and access `it.value` to set `propertyValue` `:)`. Thanks for the comment!.

Comment: What I mean was, only `proj` is enough, because `key` is passed and not used. Any Looks you updated. Thank you for your time.